# R: Grouping Time by minutes JUST at the beginning and end of each group

Tags: r

I need to calculate median of 2 minutes at the beginning and end of each group in one of the columns.

Here is the sample data:

```
Time <- c("2015-08-21T10:00:51", "2015-08-21T10:02:51", "2015-08-21T10:04:51", "2015-08-21T10:06:51", 
          "2015-08-21T10:08:51", "2015-08-21T10:10:51","2015-08-21T10:12:51", "2015-08-21T10:14:51", 
          "2015-08-21T10:16:51", "2015-08-21T10:18:51", "2015-08-21T10:20:51", "2015-08-21T10:22:51")
x <-  c(38.855, 38.664, 40.386, 40.386, 40.195, 40.386, 40.386, 40.195, 40.386, 38.855, 38.664, 40.386)
y <-  c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b")
data <- data.frame(Time,x,y)
data$Time <- as.POSIXct(data$Time, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

So in this case the median of column x of 2 minutes Time at the beginning (`"2015-08-21T10:00:51"`, `"2015-08-21T10:02:51"` so for **x** = 38.855, 38.664 **median** = 38.7595) and end ( `"2015-08-21T10:08:51"`, `"2015-08-21T10:10:51"` so for **x** = 40.195, 40.386 **median** = 40.2905) for level **a**, further for level **b** at the beginning (`"2015-08-21T10:10:51"`,`"2015-08-21T10:12:51"` so for **x** = 40.386, 40.195 **median** = 40.2905) and end (`"2015-08-21T10:20:51"`, `"2015-08-21T10:22:51"` so for **x** = 38.664, 40.386 **median** = 39.525)...

The result of this calculation would be best to get as a new data.frame like:

```
y median1 median2
a 38.7595 40.2905
b 40.2905 39.525
```

**This time grouping has to be done on base of Time column, not on base of rows counts** (as in my original data the rows are different for each of the group)

Thanks for all ideas and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it (if I got you right):

```
as.data.frame(as.list( 
  aggregate(x~y, data[order(data$Time), ], function(x) 
    c(med1=mean(head(x, 2)), med2=mean(tail(x, 2)))
  ) 
))
#   y  x.med1  x.med2
# 1 a 38.7595 40.2905
# 2 b 40.2905 39.5250
```

I don't see why the grouping has to be done on `data$Time` though. Here, it's on `data$y`. Replace `data[order(data$Time), ]` by `data` if the data set is already ordered by time.

---

For more than one variable, try

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  arrange(Time) %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  select(-Time) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% c(1, 2, n()-1, n())) %>%
  mutate(f = as.factor(rep(c("head", "tail"), each = 2))) %>%
  group_by(f, add = TRUE) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(median))
```

Comment: Can be done as well like that. However i am not sure of my original data which is sensor data. The sensor signal is taken every 2 seconds, so for 2 minutes i get around 60 rows with data (but sometimes this number varies, that is why using time column would be more safe). However this is as well good solution. one small question to it, if i have more then one x column (x1,x2), how the code would look like to get at once all median data in one data frame? Thanks

Comment: See my edit. However, this would better make a new question.

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. And You are right about making it as a new question